# TFS Build Hangs When Agent Working Directory Is Set To "$(SystemDrive)"

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, build-agent

Our TFS 2013 Server is running on Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 on Oracle Virtual Box 4.3.

I set the "Working Directory:" of the Build Agent to "$SystemDrive" as shown below. After that any build from client machine is getting hanged for ever.

Also, the VM Image is getting corrupted. Machine state can be made stable only after restoring it to a recent snapshot.

[image: Setting Working Directory to "$(SystemDrive)" Causes Hang]

The problem is straightly reproducible in our environment. Any solution is appreciated.